# Is it possible to share processing power of computer to Android Device with openCL?

Tags: opencl

Are there any good examples or demos for applying openCL to share resources(computing power, network and so on) between smart devices?

Is it possible to create super computer with thousands of smart phones?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this question is really vague. Let me tell you a very basic fact about OpenCL. OpenCL will be useful when you have heterogenous devices on the same platform. i.e. different devices like FPGA's GPU's DSP's on a single physical chip. In this case, instead of programming each chip in a different language, you can utilize the processing power and compute capacity of each device by writing code in a single language and OpenGL takes care of the compilation for the various devices. Now what you are asking for is a supercomputer between smart devices on a network. Can you use OpenCL? well in theory yes you could assuming you write a driver that somehow wirelessly pings your device and sends it a kernel to execute but even if you actually did that the cost of transferring data is tremendously high, even within the same platform, it makes sense to use a GPU/FPGA only if your data size is high and the time required to DMA/transfer data to the device is <= time for actual computation. I.e. in order to get optimum performance from your devices you need to make sure that data transfer time to your device<=time taken for computation. If these basic criteria aren't satisfied then might as well use your host CPU for computation.

Now look at your case, you want to dump OpenCL kernels to devices that are not physically connected over a network that is nondeterministic, so even in a best case time to transfer your data to the remote device will take to the tune of seconds while your computation time will be just mere milliseconds. So if you have 10 phones on a 3g/4g network and all of them are connected to a host arm processor and assuming you managed to write those drivers to make all these wireless devices detect as OpenCL devices, if you do lets say, a gaussian filter then the time that you take to send your image in parts to these devices will be exponentially higher than the time your arm processor would take to do the computation itself.

So in short what you want to do might be possible but doing it is an absolute waste of time resources and energy. And even if you actually did it, there wouldn't be much benefit in terms of performance, compute capacity etc. Think about it.